# dontnow never known

Tags: entity-relationship

Here is tha basic code:

```
i dont know
```

woop

Comment: Show us some sample table data (both tables), and also the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.)

Answer (score 1):

Just add the expression in the `SELECT` list. For example:

```
SELECT
  OrderNo, 
  PlannedQuantity, 
  CompletedQuantity + postedQuantity as CompletedQuantity, 
  IsClosed
FROM Orders
WHERE IsClosed = 0;
```